# How convert easily vkeys ALT Combination to text?

Tags: c#, raw-input

I have BarCode Scanner which writes all letters numbers over the ALT Key.

```
        id = new InputDevice(Handle);
        NumberOfKeyboards = id.EnumerateDevices();
        id.KeyPressed += new InputDevice.DeviceEventHandler(m_KeyPressed);

        private void m_KeyPressed(object sender, InputDevice.KeyControlEventArgs e)
    {

        lbHandle2.Text = e.Keyboard.deviceHandle.ToString();
        lbType.Text = e.Keyboard.deviceType;
        lbName.Text = e.Keyboard.deviceName.Replace("&", "&&");
        lbDescription.Text = e.Keyboard.Name;
        lbKey.Text = e.Keyboard.key.ToString();
        lbNumKeyboards.Text = NumberOfKeyboards.ToString();
        lbVKey.Text = e.Keyboard.vKey;
```

This is example out internet i found, i cant post my whole code of my Programm.
(lb = label)

With:

```
MyPath = MyPath + lbVKey.Text;
```

i log all my vkey events. So if my Scanner starts i get somthing like this (for A as Example)

```
MenuNumPad6Numpad5Return
```

My question is now, is there a way to quick convert it back? With DLL or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "all letters numbers over the ALT Key"?

Comment: Like i have BarCode which just says"*Hello*" the barcode Scanner is connect as HID Keyboard and writes the *H e l l o* with Alt+Numpad Combinations

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't understand what you mean.

Comment: [Link](http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html)
<---- For Example i scan a Barcode which just contains the letter **B**. Now its press on the keyboard, the keys _ALT+66_ to write a simple **B**

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689283/get-a-string-from-a-collection-of-keys-presses-retrieved-using-raw-input-api

Comment: FYI: The `visual-studio` tag reads: "do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio -- not just a coding issue". I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now i just simple catched all keys in string and converted the number to ASCII back.

```
                int unicode = int.Parse(MyConvert);
                char character = (char)unicode;
                Output = Output + character.ToString();
```

MyConvert are the Numbers which are Unicode.